# How to set function-type in interface, rather than setting function's return type

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I'm trying to define an interface with a callable field like so:

```
type MyFnType<P, R, T> = (arg: T) => Promise<R>;

declare interface PayloadActionCreatorWithFnType<P = void, R = void, T extends string = string> {
    (arg: P): MyFnType<P, R, T>;
    type: T;
}
```

Issue I'm running into is that above defines an object that when invoked `obj()` returns  `MyFunType`. What I want is to set the TYPE for that callable function rather than setting the return type for that function.

I can achieve the same thing via

```
declare interface PayloadActionCreatorWithFnType<P = void, R = void, T extends string = string> {
    (arg: P): Promise<R>;
    type: T;
}
```

```
// Real application

const impl = (arg: string): Promise<string> => {
    return new Promise(res => {});
};
impl.type = 'type';

const obj1: PayloadActionCreator<string, string, string> = impl; // no ts error
const obj2: PayloadActionCreatorWithFnType<string, string, string> = impl; // returns error
```

I want to use a FuncType for my case above because I want to reuse that type in other spots.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for .  Is [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBLAdgFxDAZlMCAKUAnhAPZTACCYqiJyAwnFKiTAOqKoAWAYsgCqEADiAA8AKHhT4eeAF54ANxKJgAGngAleUpXr4-eCAAe6ZMADO8C6hgoA5jpt3k9gHzwA3pOkAKWPYAXDIAlMF4MCQAtogWYppuANw+UqjCIMH8yQC+4uJgdDZIUUIQOv4wQda2DmEykTFxos4OHnIe3tLwcKgArjDI8MggAO710bEgvnBW7V7w2SE5yYglEAB0aSI6AORbIDvJ+YWo8CQARgBW4USk5FQ0dIwgzKwc3HyCIs01rhotf2qLncOlWpWS8HEQA) not good enough for you?  Can you elaborate? Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz basically similar to what you did. In your case you defined the RETURN type of the func. What I want is to define the TYPE of the func, not the return type. Hope that helps.

Comment: `(arg: P): MyFnType<P, R, T>` returns a function.  Are you asking for `(arg: P): ReturnType<MyFnType<P, R, T>>;`?

Comment: Ahh yes, that'll do! So I guess there is no other way to set the return type other than using `ReturnType<...>`?

Comment: I don't understand what you might mean about another way to set the return type.  Maybe you want  `type PayloadActionCreatorWithFnType<P = void, R = void, T extends string = string> = MyFnType<"this param is unused?!", P, R> & { type: T }`?

Comment: Ah nice -- yeah something like that. Thanks!!

Comment: I'll add that to my answer when I get a chance then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might just be looking for the [`ReturnType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet) utility type:

```
declare interface PayloadActionCreatorWithFnType<
    P = void, R = void, T extends string = string> {
    (arg: P): ReturnType<MyFnType<P, R, T>>;
    type: T;
}
```

That utility type is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) to extract the return type of a function type.  It's [defined](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.9.5/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1506) like this:

```
type ReturnType<T extends (...args: any) => any> = 
  T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any;
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiA7AKuCAeACgGigJV2QD4oBeKACgEMAnAcwC4pkBKMkzGgewFsBLAM4Y8RANwAocQBMIAYwA2taH0TAINAGZVZ0TFRDyuVKQEFZwPl0QBhGhCrAuNAOp9gACySpI6cVH9QmGRQAG5cfFK4eMFhEYRQEAAeaohSAlACwDQqdMGZ2Yh0JADefgHU9EyYLEx4EMAArjQoaOhwXq04+IREYmX+oJBMyBIAvpKyVplQfDxg8sEVjBlZOTWB3PxC6Pk5JKQl-VB2jc1QiBAA7hu8ghAUdukHUMVQoyxjErPzAHSD0OQAOT-QEScSTRDTLgAIwAVlV9IZjGYLFZbPZHC43J4Wj5doVcPi6ITVoV9jM5vIwVAgA)